# Emberjs filtered select collection update

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I made a JsBin where i demonstrate my problem:

### http://jsbin.com/pexolude/69/edit

**Explonation:**

In the first select i have customers. This select's value (customer_value) filters the 2nd select's (contactPersons) collection. If you select a customer, the "New Contact Person" button will be enabled. On click it adds a new Contact Person "Dale" to the Double R Diner.
*(In my app it is a form and the new contact person will be add to the selected customer)*

**The test**

- Select "Double R Diner"
- Add New Contact Person (Dale is added, but he is not on the Double R Diner's contact Persons list )
- Change to "Great Northen Hotel"
- Go back to "Double R Diner" -> Dale is on the list

It would be nice to have the **contact_persons** property auto-updated when a new element is added. Shouldnt this be the default behaviour? Or i have to trigger it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally, a good rule of thumb, is to look at all of the properties that are required in your computed property, and if any of them make a difference in the value of the computed property (which I'd assume they all do), then they should be defined in the property method.

In this case, you will want to watch each property on a collection, for that we use the `@each` keyword.  It's important to note, you can't go more than one level deep with `@each`.  http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/

```
  contact_persons: function(){
    var id = parseInt(this.get('customer_value'),10);
    return this.get('contactPersons').filterBy('partner.id',id);
  }.property('customer_value', 'contactPersons.@each.partner'),
```

What we're saying here is any time any new record is added/removed to contactPersons, or the `partner` property changes on any of them (`partner` itself, not `partner.foo`, the `partner` reference must change) then the property is dirty.

Example: http://jsbin.com/pexolude/72/edit